# How to write JQuery function to display text in special location of Django template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I'm trying to create my first ajax function in Django. 
I want to change my code using JQuery, the idea is pretty simple: 
User type a subject name and this name is displayed in subject-list below the form,

The problem is I don't really know what to type in JQuery function.

```
JQuery:
function create_subject() {
    $("input").focus(function(){
        var subject = $(this).val();
        $(".btn-create").click(function(){

            /* What I need to write in here */

        });
    });
}
```

In HTML "subjects" refer to database.

```
 HTML 
    <div id="subjects-list">
                    {% if user.username %}
                        <ul>
                            {% if subjects %}
                                <form method="post" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
                                {% for subject in subjects %}
   -------- TYPED TEXT SHOULD BE HERE -------->         <li><a href="/user/{{ user.username }}/subject/{{ subject.name }}/">{{ subject.name }}</a></li>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </form>
                            {% else %}
                                <p>No Subjects for this user</p>
                            {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                    {% else %}
                            You are in else
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
```

That's how HTML looks in "View Page Source"

```
    <div id="create-subject">
        <form method="post" action="."> <div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='cfbd1893742c3ab9936bacaae9653051' /></div>
            <p><label for="id_name">Subject Name:</label> <input id="id_name" type="text" name="name" size="9" /></p>
            <input type="button" name="subject-create-b" value="Create Subject" class="btn-create"/>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div id="subjects-list">

            <ul>

                    <form method="post" action="."><div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='cfbd1893742c3ab9936bacaae9653051' /></div>

                        <li><a href="/user/r/subject/Math 140/">Math 140</a><span id="subject-link"></span></li>

                    </form>

            </ul>

    </div>
</div>
```

And that's my form

```
forms.py
class SubjectCreationForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Subject Name", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':9}))

    class Meta:
        exclude = ('created_by', 'created_time', 'num_of_followers', 'vote')
    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if len(name)>1:
            return name
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Subject name should be longer")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do what (I think) you want to do which is some basic AJAX using Django as your backend, you'll need the following:

1. A view which returns the data you want to load

   - There are a number of ways you can represent the data, but to keep it simple, I'll use HTML.
2. Javascript to load that view (using JQuery if you like)

Your code might look like this for the first part:

**urls.py:**

```
...

(r'^get-subjects/$', 'yourapp.views.get_subjects'),

...
```

**views.py:**

```
...

def get_subjects(request):
    subjects = # code to fetch your subjects.
    return render_to_response('subjects_template.html', {'subjects': subjects})

...
```

**subjects_template.html:**

```
{% for subject in subjects %}
    <li>{{ subject.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

For the second part, it might look like this:

**main_template.html:**

```
...

<ul id="subjects-list"></ul>

<script>
function loadSubjects() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/get-subjects",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#subjects-list").html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>

...
```

[1] [render_to_response()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response)

[2] [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

This will get you most the way there.  When you want to reload the list, you call the `loadSubjects()` function.

As far as creating the subjects go, that is a different thing.  What you'll want to look into is how to do an HTML form submission without leaving the page.  There are plenty of tools and libraries to do that stuff with a nice api.  If you want to stick with JQuery, you might consider [this plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/) for a nicer api.

Answer (score 1):

```
function create_subject() {
    $("input").focus(function(){
        var subject = $(this).val();
        $(".btn-create").click(function(){    
            $('#subjects-list').append(subject);    
        });
    });
}
```

that said, you probably don't want to assign the click handler every time the input is focused.  i'd move that out of the focus handler.